# Syntax Error in Django urls.py

Tags: python, django

I'm having a frustrating time installing a very simple recipes website for myself using Django. Everything has been going fine until I attempt to set up my urls.py, which reads:

```
from django.conf.urls.defaults import *
from django.contrib import admin
from timsrecipes.recipes import views
admin.autodiscover()


urlpatterns = patterns('',
      (r'^index/$', views.index),
      (r'^search/$',views.search),
      (r'^ingredientsearch/$', views.ingredientsearch),
      (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
)
```

The database containing the recipes has been set up, validated, and synchronized, but when I attempt to access any of the webpages, I get the following error message:

Exception Value:    ('invalid syntax', ('/Users/mary/Programming-Startup/timsrecipes/../timsrecipes/recipes/views.py', 13, 10, '         )\n'))

Exception Location: /Users/mary/Programming-Startup/timsrecipes/../timsrecipes/urls.py in , line 3

I really cannot see what the syntax error is here. Several other small websites I've built have this same formula for importing their views, so I cannot understand what the problem could be.

Comment: Your error is in views.py. Give us it's source code.

Answer (score 4):

The exception is not in urls.py, it's in recipes/views.py, line 13.